# InfoPath getting the ID not the value I configured in lookup field

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2013, infopath, infopath-data-connections

I have two lists setup:

Office: only has title field
LOB Manager: has responsible person and a lookup column to the Office list.

The office lookup in LOB Manager is configured to use the Title field in the office list.

In InfoPath I have configured the two above lists as data sources. I found that the LOB Manager drop down was always empty. When I did some digging I found that the LOB Manager source was bringing back the ID of the office not the Title as I configured in the lookup column.

This is a deal breaker for us to not have the sub list drop downs filtering off the office selection.

I have redone the lookup but InfoPath insists on using the ID not the Title.

Anyone got any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

InfoPath offers this dialog to configure a drop-down:

[image]

Make sure that the "Display Name" is set to the Title and the "Value" to the ID. Internally, only the ID is stored in the SharePoint list. The SharePoint view will resolve the title.

If you use a SharePoint Lookup column and edit the form with InfoPath, the settings are correct by default.